# Use variable multiple times in PHPUnit without having to get it again

Tags: php, phpunit, global-variables

I'm developping some tests with phpUnit and in a chain of tests I need to pass throw an authorization situation. And for this I HAVE TO connect to the data-base and get an Entity that cannot be mocked. However, if I do this in the setUp() it will connect to the database once for each test I'm running.

How can I connect and get this Entity in the database once and then use it in all the tests?

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setApplicationConfig(include './config/application.config.php');
    parent::setUp();

    $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
    $this->instituicao = $serviceManager->get('InstituicaoRepository')->getByUrl('uov');
}
```

The variable `$this->instituicao` have to come from the Database, and so, I need to get it only once. But setUp call it multiple times.

I tried something like this:

```
private $instituicao;

public function getSharedInstituicao()
{
    if($this->instituicao == null){
        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();

        $this->instituicao = $serviceManager->get('InstituicaoRepository')->getByUrl('uov');
    }

    return $this->instituicao;
}
```

And removed it from setUp and called this function when needed, but it was  null and fetching into the DB every time.

Comment: A concrete example would help.

Comment: @tadman put some of my code, I hope it can help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe shared fixtuere will help
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture? Try `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass`

Comment: I haven't tried this one yet. Gonna see how it works.

Comment: Didn't work =/ I can't use `$this->` inside `setUpbeforeClass`

Comment: @DavidAlves Maybe for the need of the test you can create InstituicaoRepository instance in setUpBeforeClass. You not testing service manager and is not crucial to use it here